# Using UNION and <condition> to select Names starting with A to K

Tags: sqlite, union, between

I'm solving challenge. There are 2 tables:
`Fruit` with columns `FriutID` and `Name`

And table `Vegetables` with columns `VegetableID` and `Name`

I need to output a list of all friuts and vegetables starting with letters A through K. In other words all fruit and vegetables that don't start with the letter L to Z.

I'm using `UNION`, but I don't know how to use `LIKE "selection criteria"`

```
select Name from fruit where Name LIKE BETWEEN "A%" AND "K%"
        UNION 
select Name from vegetable where Name LIKE BETWEEN "A%" AND "K%";
```

My second attempt:

```
    select Name from fruit where Name LIKE "A%" AND LIKE "B%" AND LIKE "C%" AND LIKE "D%" AND LIKE "E%" AND LIKE "F%" AND LIKE "G%" 
AND LIKE "H%" AND LIKE "I%" AND LIKE "J%" AND LIKE "K%"
        UNION 
select Name from vegetable where Name LIKE "A%" AND LIKE "B%" AND LIKE "C%" AND LIKE "D%" AND LIKE "E%" AND LIKE "F%" AND LIKE "G%" 
AND LIKE "H%" AND LIKE "I%" AND LIKE "J%" AND LIKE "K%";
```

It returns with syntax error: `SQL Error: near ""B%"": syntax error`

Please suggest a solution how to solve this,
Kind regards,
Anna

Answer (score 0):

You're close with the second attempt. But you need to use `OR` -- a name can ever begin with one letter and also with another letter the same time. And you need to use a full `LIKE` operation -- you cannot use the first operand for more than one second operand.

```
SELECT name
       FROM fruit
       WHERE name LIKE 'A%'
              OR name LIKE 'B%'
             ...
               OR name LIKE 'J%';
                OR name LIKE 'K%'
UNION
SELECT name
       FROM vegetable
       WHERE name LIKE 'A%'
              OR name LIKE 'B%'
             ...
               OR name LIKE 'J%';
                OR name LIKE 'K%';
```

Also note that `UNION` eliminates duplicates. If you don't need or want that use `UNION ALL` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much @sticky bit , works like magic!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `LIKE`, which can't be used with the operator `BETWEEN`, use `SUBSTR()` to get the 1st letter of each `Name` and check if it is between `'A'` and `'K'`:

```
SELECT Name FROM fruit WHERE UPPER(SUBSTR(Name, 1, 1)) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'K'
UNION ALL 
SELECT Name FROM vegetable WHERE UPPER(SUBSTR(Name, 1, 1)) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'K';
```

Or with the [`GLOB`](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_and_match_operators) operator:

```
SELECT Name FROM fruit WHERE Name GLOB '[A-Ka-k]*'
UNION ALL 
SELECT Name FROM vegetable WHERE Name GLOB '[A-Ka-k]*';
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand the logic. Solved the challenge, so doesn't let me to try solution with SUBSTR or GLOB. Maybe I will try when I see similar task next time. Many thanks!